# System becomes unresponsive after power return from APC UPS

Tags: ssh, dell, power-management, battery, ups

I have a Dell T5600 workstation with ubuntu 20.04 running on it. I have a APC RS 1500G-IN UPS connected to the machine via USB cable and has apcupsd service running on it. I live in a place where short very frequent power failures takes place constantly, like 2 to 3 short 5-15 min power failures in an hour sometimes. I have noticed that, my ubuntu system properly recognises that a power failure has occurred and broadcasts a message saying its now running on batteries. However when the power returns, the system goes to this state where I am able to ping the machine but not able to ssh into it. The screen is generally completely blank with a curser at the very top of the screen and the system does not respond to any keyboard strokes either. I have to do a hard reboot for it to connect back. I have no idea why this might be happening. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: SSH from where and does all the equipment have backup power?

Comment: I ssh from my laptop to this machine. All over my local network. I have power backup to my router as well through which both the systems are connected. So yes, all the equipment has power.